# How do you check if a struct is initialized in C?

Tags: c

I declared a struct and I want to check if it has been initialized yet. How do I do this?

I've tried:

```
struct mystruct str1;

if(str1 != NULL)

if(str1->name != NULL)
```

The struct is a linked list, and also contains properties of type int and char among others.

Comment: Surely, it won't initialize automagically. Just keep track of when you initialize it?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the short hand dereference -> syntax is for pointers only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you declare the struct *outside* of any function *including `main()`*, the struct and its contents will be initialized to zero. As pointed out in the comments, that means different things for different data types.

1. integers (e.g. char, short, int, long, unsigned, unsigned int, long long, etc..) will be 0
2. float and double will be numeric 0.0 [but the bytes they are comprised of may not be]
3. pointers will be NULL
4. struct padding may be undefined.
5. arrays will be zeroed as appropriate for their type.

If you define the struct or any variables non-static within a function, they are undefined. On some implementations they happen to contain whatever is on the stack in many implementations, but that is architecture-dependent. In any case, you can assume structs, arrays and variables that are declared in a function without the static word in front of them are *uninitialized and contain garbage*.

You normally would not test to see if a struct is initialized, you just have to know the circumstances you defined the in, and whether you've initialized it (and its subelements) or not.

The only way you could determine if a struct was initialized would be to check each element within it to see if it matched what you considered an initialized value for that element should be.  If you want to check to see if a pointer to a struct is initialized to a pre-defined state, you'd just see if it contains either NULL or a specific address you initialized it to.

Comment: They are neither guaranteed to be all `0` nor to be `NULL`. `struct` members are initialized to an appropriate zero representation. Pointers are `NULL`'d, `float`s and `double`s get whatever value signifies a zero for them and normal integers are zeroed. Padding on the other hand isn't touched.

Comment: @a3f - Thanks for the clarification. That's an important distinction.  But they are initialized to sensible values.  No one cares about padding generally speaking but in rare cases that might matter, and people usually check floats and doubles for zero, but your point that if you pass them by reference or cast them, they might not be zero is taken. Thanks.

Comment: Agree with most - pedantic exception: "they contain whatever is on the stack" may or may not be true.  C does not even specify a stack.  (see Harvard architecture use in many embedded processors.  Best said that the local non-static values are undefined and leave it at that.

Comment: Another detail : "determine if a struct was initialized would be to check each element" may lead to UB.  Example, a value could have a trap value, so reading before setting it is the end of the program.

Comment: @chux, I'm going to update my answer based on what you and a3f said.

Comment: @a3f - I updated my answer to match the points you clarified.